# How can I select two indexes in a JList, and two items in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, indexing, jcombobox, jlist

Okay, I have a Jlist, a combobox, and an order and a Stats JButton; I have several selections in both the Jlist and the Jcombobox. After I click order a couple of times, varying the selections each time, I want the Stats button, after I click on it, to open up a JFrame revealing the most popular selections and the least popular selections in both the Jlist and Jcombobox. I have found out how to reveal the most popular in its JTextField, but I'm having a hard time revealing the least. Here is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class FoodClass extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame jfStats;
    JButton jbStats, jbOrder;
    JList jlFood;
    DefaultListModel dlmFood;
    JComboBox jcbSize;
    JTextField jtfPopularFd, jtfUnpopularFd, jtfPopularSz, jtfUnpopularSz;
    JLabel jlabPopular, jlabUnpopular, jlabTitle;
    JPanel jpTop, jpMiddle;
    int[] foodArr = new int[5];
    int[] sizeArr = new int[3];
    public void init()
    {
        //Just the GUI (Skip down to the next method)
        System.out.println("Applet opened");
        jlabTitle = new JLabel("Mickey's");
        jfStats = new JFrame();
        jbStats = new JButton("Stats");
        jbOrder = new JButton("Order");
        dlmFood = new DefaultListModel();
        jlFood = new JList(dlmFood);
        dlmFood.addElement("Cheeseburger w/ Fries & Drink");
        dlmFood.addElement("Dbl Cheeseburger w/ Fries & Drink");
        dlmFood.addElement("Big N' Tasty w/ Fries & Drink");
        dlmFood.addElement("Dbl Qtr Pounder w/ Fries & Drink");
        dlmFood.addElement("Big Mac w/ Fries & Drink");
        jcbSize = new JComboBox();
        jcbSize.addItem("Small");
        jcbSize.addItem("Medium");
        jcbSize.addItem("Large");
        jbStats.addActionListener(this);
        jbOrder.addActionListener(this);
        jpTop = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jpTop.add(jlabTitle);
        jpMiddle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jpMiddle.add(jlFood);
        jpMiddle.add(jcbSize);
        jpMiddle.add(jbOrder);
        jpMiddle.add(jbStats);
        add(jpTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jpMiddle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == jbOrder) processjbOrder();
        if(src == jbStats) processjbStats();
    }
    public void processjbOrder()
    {
        int foodInt = jlFood.getSelectedIndex();
        int sizeInt = jcbSize.getSelectedIndex();
        foodArr[foodInt]++;//Increasing the selected Array by 1 every time the Order button is
        //pressed
        System.out.println("Food Ind = "+foodArr[foodInt]);
        sizeArr[sizeInt]++;
        System.out.println("Size Ind = "+sizeArr[sizeInt]);
    }
    public void processjbStats()
    {
        jfStats.setVisible(true);//opening the JFrame when the stats button is pressed
        jfStats.setSize(200, 200);
        jlabPopular = new JLabel("Most Popular");
        jlabUnpopular = new JLabel("Least Popular");
        jtfPopularFd = new JTextField(10);
        jtfUnpopularFd = new JTextField(10);
        jtfPopularSz = new JTextField(10);
        jtfUnpopularSz = new JTextField(10);
        jfStats.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfStats.add(jlabPopular); jfStats.add(jtfPopularFd); jfStats.add(jtfPopularSz);
        jfStats.add(jlabUnpopular); jfStats.add(jtfUnpopularFd); jfStats.add(jtfUnpopularSz);
        int mostPFood = findMax(foodArr);
        System.out.println("Most Popular Food = "+mostPFood);
        int mostPSize = findMax(sizeArr);
        System.out.println("Most Popular Size = "+mostPSize);
        int leastPFood = findLeast(foodArr);
        System.out.println("Least Popular Food = "+leastPFood);
        int leastPSize = findLeast(sizeArr);
        System.out.println("Least Popular Size = "+leastPSize);
        //Getting the names of the selected Indexes as opposed to the numbers
        jlFood.setSelectedIndex(mostPFood); 
        jlFood.setSelectedIndex(leastPFood);
        jcbSize.setSelectedItem(mostPSize);
        jcbSize.setSelectedItem(leastPSize);
        String strMostFd = (String) jlFood.getSelectedValue();//Trouble here
        String strLeastFd = (String) jlFood.getSelectedValue();
        String strMostSz = (String) jcbSize.getSelectedItem();
        String strLeastSz = (String) jcbSize.getSelectedItem();
        jtfPopularFd.setText(strMostFd);
        jtfUnpopularFd.setText(strLeastFd);
        jtfPopularSz.setText(strMostSz);
        jtfUnpopularSz.setText(strLeastSz);
    }
    private int findMax(int[] intMax)//Finding the most popular selection
    {
        int largest = intMax[0];
        int maxInd = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<intMax.length;i++)
            if(intMax[i]>largest)
            {
                largest = intMax[i];
                maxInd = i;
            }
        return maxInd;
    }
    private int findLeast(int[] intLeast)//Finding the least popular selection
    {
        int smallest = intLeast[0];
        int leastInd = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<intLeast.length;i++)
            if(1>=intLeast[i] && intLeast[i]<smallest)//Trying to find out how to find the
                //least popular selection, that was ACTUALLY SELECTED...
            {
                smallest = intLeast[i];
                leastInd = i;
            }
        return leastInd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in your findLeast method that in the if statement, you have

```
1>=intLeast[i]
```

while it should be

```
1<=intLeast[i]
```

so that you're making sure it was selected at least once instead of only once or none.

Personally, I find it clearer to place the thing you're trying to compare on the left side:

```
intLeast[i]>=1
```

**Edit**: To answer your comment (I didn't realize the scope of the problem before):
It's not possible to set 2 different values on a JComboBox in Swing. It is possible on a JList; however, the way you're attempting to do that is not the way to go about setting the min and max in the stats window, and not necessary.

Where you're doing this:
`jlFood.setSelectedIndex(mostPFood);`
`jlFood.setSelectedIndex(leastPFood);`
`jcbSize.setSelectedItem(mostPSize);`
`jcbSize.setSelectedItem(leastPSize);`
you should not be; you can remove those lines. You don't need to change values in an existing component because you already have the min and max indexes. You should not change input selections just to do calculations about them. You should only change input selections when the inputs you want the user to choose from changes, i.e. if selecting from one component changes what the user should be able to choose from in another component.

I would declare the values for each component in an array so that you will have an easy way to map the indexes to the values.  Something like this:
`String[] foodArrVals = {"Cheeseburger w/ Fries & Drink",`
`"Dbl Cheeseburger w/ Fries & Drink",`
`"Big N' Tasty w/ Fries & Drink",`
`"Dbl Qtr Pounder w/ Fries & Drink",`
`"Big Mac w/ Fries & Drink"};`

Then instead of populating those elements the way you're doing into the JList, you can do it within a for loop iterating over foodArrVals.
Also, instead of your line:
`String strMostFd = (String) jlFood.getSelectedValue();`
`String strLeastFd = (String) jlFood.getSelectedValue();`
since you already have the index of the most selected, and now you have the easy mapping from index to value through the array, you can do this:
`String strMostFd = foodArrVals[mostPFood];`
`String strLeastFd = foodArrVals[leastPFood];`

You can do the same for the size selections.
Alternatively, if you didn't want to declare the array of values up front (though I think that's the best way in this case), you could do something like this:
`String strMostFd = (String) jlFood.getItemAt(mostPFood);`

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how i would reveal two selections from the JList; i.e., the most selected and the least selected.